# Numpy quirk: Apply function to all pairs of two 1D arrays, to get one 2D array

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

Let's say I have 2 one-dimensional (1D) numpy arrays, `a` and `b`, with lengths `n1` and `n2` respectively. I also have a function, `F(x,y)`,  that takes two values. Now I want to apply that function to each pair of values from my two 1D arrays, so the result would be a 2D numpy array with shape `n1, n2`. The `i, j` element of the two-dimensional array would be `F(a[i], b[j])`.

I haven't been able to find a way of doing this without a horrible amount of for-loops, and I'm sure there's a much simpler (and faster!) way of doing this in numpy.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it possible you're looking for an outer product type function with a scalar?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use [numpy broadcasting](http://scipy-lectures.github.io/intro/numpy/operations.html#broadcasting) to do calculation on the two arrays, turning `a` into a vertical 2D array using `newaxis`:

```
In [11]: a = np.array([1, 2, 3]) # n1 = 3
    ...: b = np.array([4, 5]) # n2 = 2
    ...: #if function is c(i, j) = a(i) + b(j)*2:
    ...: c = a[:, None] + b*2

In [12]: c
Out[12]: 
array([[ 9, 11],
       [10, 12],
       [11, 13]])
```

To benchmark:

```
In [28]: a = arange(100)

In [29]: b = arange(222)

In [30]: timeit r = np.array([[f(i, j) for j in b] for i in a])
10 loops, best of 3: 29.9 ms per loop

In [31]: timeit c = a[:, None] + b*2
10000 loops, best of 3: 71.6 us per loop
```

Comment: `newaxis` may be a formal way to add a new axis to ndarray, even if they are the same.

Comment: Yes, they are the same in the internal code. But `newaxis` is easier to understand, something more like a grammar sugar.

Comment: This looks like what I'm looking for, I will try it out immediately!

Comment: This works great! Could this be expanded to comparing two 2D arrays? So the result would be that function of each pair of columns between the two 2D arrays

Comment: assuming that I have a numpy array and I want to apply a function in row pairs and accumulate the result e.g. row0+row1 , output of this + row3 etc, how can I do this in a smart way?

Answer (score 15):

If `F` is beyond your control, you can wrap it automatically to be "vector-aware" by using `numpy.vectorize`. I present a working example below where I define my own `F` just for completeness. This approach has the simplicity advantage, but if you have control over `F`, rewriting it with a bit of care to vectorize correctly can have huge speed benefits

```
import numpy

n1 = 100
n2 = 200

a = numpy.arange(n1)
b = numpy.arange(n2)

def F(x, y):
    return x + y

# Everything above this is setup, the answer to your question lies here:
fv = numpy.vectorize(F)
r = fv(a[:, numpy.newaxis], b)
```

On my computer, the following timings are found, showing the price you pay for "automatic" vectorisation:

```
%timeit fv(a[:, numpy.newaxis], b)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.58 ms per loop

%timeit F(a[:, numpy.newaxis], b)
10000 loops, best of 3: 38.3 µs per loop
```

Comment: I suggest this `In [5]: %timeit a[:, numpy.newaxis] + b`
`49.9 µs ± 337 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)`

Comment: Beautiful! Very generic answer which deserves a clear question in its own right. A lot of this is about language - broadcasting, outer product, reduce, correlator with arbitrary function, .... Are there any circumstances in which your method would fail? Can np.vectorize work on an arbitrary function/lambda? And if not?

Comment: @jtlz2 `numpy.vectorise` works on all functions since it effectively works as a for loop (see the note in [the docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html)). So vectorise is a quick way to avoid writing the for loop yourself, but as I show it doesn't actualy makes the code run any faster. To do that you'd need to use one of the other techniques you mention.

Answer (score 3):

If `F()` works with broadcast arguments, definitely use that, as others describe.
An alternative is to use
[np.fromfunction](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromfunction.html)
(`function_on_an_int_grid` would be a better name.)
The following just maps the int grid to your a-b grid, then into `F()`:

```
import numpy as np

def func_allpairs( F, a, b ):
    """ -> array len(a) x len(b):
        [[ F( a0 b0 )  F( a0 b1 ) ... ]
         [ F( a1 b0 )  F( a1 b1 ) ... ]
         ...
        ]
    """
    def fab( i, j ):
        return F( a[i], b[j] )  # F scalar or vec, e.g. gradient

    return np.fromfunction( fab, (len(a), len(b)), dtype=int )  # -> fab( all pairs )


#...............................................................................
def F( x, y ):
    return x + 10*y

a = np.arange( 100 )
b = np.arange( 222 )
A = func_allpairs( F, a, b )
# %timeit: 1000 loops, best of 3: 241 µs per loop -- imac i5, np 1.9.3
```

Comment: I really like how generalizable this method is for all-pairs matrices with two 1D vectors.

Answer (score 2):

You could use **list comprehensions** to create an array of arrays:

```
import numpy as np

# Arrays
a = np.array([1, 2, 3]) # n1 = 3
b = np.array([4, 5]) # n2 = 2

# Your function (just an example)
def f(i, j):
    return i + j

result = np.array([[f(i, j)for j in b ]for i in a])
print result
```

**Output:**

```
[[5 6]
 [6 7]
 [7 8]]
```

Comment: List comprehensions are little better than for loops for NumPy code.

Comment: That's mine. I've already provided feedback, but I'll elaborate. List comprehensions can shorten code, but they will be just as slow as loop-based solutions. When working with NumPy, it's a good habit to always look for a solution using NumPy's vectorized operations first.

Comment: This is much slower than the other options.

Answer (score 2):

As another alternative that's a bit more extensible than the dot-product, in less than 1/5th - 1/9th the time of nested list comprehensions, use `numpy.newaxis` ([took a bit more digging to find](http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/numpy-discussion/2007-August/028915.html)):

```
>>> import numpy
>>> a = numpy.array([0,1,2])
>>> b = numpy.array([0,1,2,3])
```

This time, using the power function:

```
>>> pow(a[:,numpy.newaxis], b)
array([[1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 2, 4, 8]])
```

Compared with an alternative:

```
>>> numpy.array([[pow(i,j) for j in b] for i in a])
array([[1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 2, 4, 8]])
```

And comparing the timing:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit('numpy.array([[pow(i,j) for i in a] for j in b])', 'import numpy; a=numpy.arange(3); b=numpy.arange(4)')
31.943181037902832
>>> timeit.timeit('pow(a[:, numpy.newaxis], b)', 'import numpy; a=numpy.arange(3); b=numpy.arange(4)')
5.985810041427612

>>> timeit.timeit('numpy.array([[pow(i,j) for i in a] for j in b])', 'import numpy; a=numpy.arange(10); b=numpy.arange(10)')
109.74687385559082
>>> timeit.timeit('pow(a[:, numpy.newaxis], b)', 'import numpy; a=numpy.arange(10); b=numpy.arange(10)')
11.989138126373291
```

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest, if your use-case is more limited to products, [that you use the outer-product?](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.outer.html)

e.g.:

```
import numpy

a = array([0, 1, 2])
b = array([0, 1, 2, 3])

numpy.outer(a,b)
```

returns

```
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 2, 3],
       [0, 2, 4, 6]])
```

You can then apply other transformations:

```
numpy.outer(a,b) + 1
```

returns

```
array([[1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 2, 3, 4],
       [1, 3, 5, 7]])
```

This is much faster:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit('numpy.array([[i*j for i in a] for j in b])', 'import numpy; a=numpy.arange(3); b=numpy.arange(4)')
31.79583477973938

>>> timeit.timeit('numpy.outer(a,b)', 'import numpy; a=numpy.arange(3); b=numpy.arange(4)')
9.351550102233887
>>> timeit.timeit('numpy.outer(a,b)+1', 'import numpy; a=numpy.arange(3); b=numpy.arange(4)')
12.308301210403442
```

Comment: interesting, but does this not assume that the function always takes the product of the two input values? What if you wanted a more complicated function?

Comment: That's fair, but this is an incredibly common operation, relative to others you might want. If you want a more complicated function, may I suggest my other answer here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21226610/numpy-quirk-apply-function-to-all-pairs-of-two-1d-arrays-to-get-one-2d-array/21273998#21273998 If I may be slightly presumptuous, would you be willing to share your mystery function?