# Generate pairs from a numpy array in a specific pattern without loops

Tags: python, numpy

Let's consider an array [1,2,3] say, what I would like to generate is the list containing the pairs [[1,2], [1,3], [2,3]]. This can be done  using [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations/). However, I would like to produce them using pure numpy operations, and no loops or branching is allowed.

A close solution is provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21226896/9548133), but it generates all the possible pairs, instead of a particular fashion as in my case.

Can you please suggest a way to do that? The array will always be 1D.

Also, this is my first question on SE. If it requires any edit, please let me know.

Comment: A slightly more general (pairs, triplets, etc.) solution is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42202157/7207392) it has a loop, but since in your case the size of subsets is fixed at 2 this can be eliminated. Or you could use `triu_indices`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a one-liner using `np.triu_indices`:

```
>>> a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
>>> a[np.transpose(np.triu_indices(len(a), 1))]
array([[1, 2],
       [1, 3],
       [2, 3]])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!  This is certainly helpful.