# Convert to indices array in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Similar to `retrun_inverse` in `numpy.unique`,

if I have a numpy array a:`[['a' 'b'] ['b' 'c'] ['c' 'c'] ['c' 'b']]`,

I want to convert array b:`[['b' 'c'] ['a' 'b'] ['c' 'c'] ['a' 'b'] ['c' 'c']]` to `[1 0 2 0 2]`.

Is there any smart way to convert it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this is more easily done with plain `list`s (which you can get from NumPy arrays with `.tolist()` method):

```
a = [['a', 'b'], ['b', 'c'], ['c', 'c'], ['c', 'b']]
b = [['b', 'c'], ['a', 'b'], ['c', 'c'], ['a', 'b'], ['c', 'c']]

print([a.index(x) for x in b])
# [1, 0, 2, 0, 2]
```

or, writing it as a function and assuming NumPy arrays inputs and outputs and handling the case where a needle is not in the haystack:

```
import numpy as np


def find_by_list(haystack, needles):
    haystack = haystack.tolist()
    result = []
    for needle in needles.tolist():
        try:
            result.append(haystack.index(needle))
        except ValueError:
            result.append(-1)
    return np.array(result)
```

---

This comes out approximately as fast as a more NumPy-aware solutions based on `np.where()` (provided that the reduction operated by `np.all()` can be done on the first axis), e.g.:

```
import numpy as np


def find_by_np(haystack, needles, haystack_axis=-1, needles_axis=-1, keepdims=False):
    if haystack_axis:
        haystack = haystack.swapaxes(0, haystack_axis)
    if needles_axis:
        needles = needles.swapaxes(0, needles_axis)
    n = needles.shape[0]
    m = haystack.ndim - 1
    shape = haystack.shape[1:]
    result = np.full((m,) + needles.shape[1:], -1)
    haystack = haystack.reshape(n, -1)
    needles = needles.reshape(n, -1)
    _, match, index = np.nonzero(np.all(
        haystack[:, None, :] == needles[:, :, None],
        axis=0, keepdims=True))
    result.reshape(m, -1)[:, match] = np.unravel_index(index, shape)
    if not keepdims and result.shape[0] == 1:
        result = np.squeeze(result, 0)
    return result
```

but both are slower than simple loops accelerated with Numba JIT, e.g.:

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb


def find_by_loop(haystack, needles):
    n, m = haystack.shape
    l, m_ = needles.shape
    result = np.full(l, -1)
    if m != m_:
        return result
    for i in range(l):
        for j in range(n):
            is_equal = True
            for k in range(m):
                if haystack[j, k] != needles[i, k]:
                    is_equal = False
                    break
            if is_equal:
                break
        if is_equal:
            result[i] = j
    return result


find_by_nb = nb.jit(find_by_loop)
find_by_nb.__name__ = 'find_by_nb'
```

---

While they all give the same result:

```
funcs = find_by_list, find_by_np, find_by_loop, find_by_nb


a = np.array([['a', 'b'], ['b', 'c'], ['c', 'c'], ['c', 'b']])
b = np.array([['b', 'c'], ['a', 'b'], ['c', 'c'], ['a', 'b'], ['c', 'c']])
print(a.shape, b.shape)
for func in funcs:
    print(f'{func.__name__:>12s}(a, b) = {func(a, b)}')
# find_by_list(a, b) = [1 0 2 0 2]
#   find_by_np(a, b) = [1 0 2 0 2]
# find_by_loop(a, b) = [1 0 2 0 2]
#   find_by_nb(a, b) = [1 0 2 0 2]
```

The timings comes as follows:

```
print(f'({"n":<4s}, {"m":<4s}, {"k":<4s})', end='  ')
for func in funcs:
    print(f'{func.__name__:>15s}', end='    ')
print()
for n, m, k in itertools.product((5, 50, 500), repeat=3):
    a = np.random.randint(0, 100, (k, n))
    b = np.random.randint(0, 100, (m, n))
    print(f'({n:<4d}, {m:<4d}, {k:<4d})', end='  ')
    for func in funcs:
        result = %timeit -n3 -r10 -q -o func(a, b)
        print(f'{result.best * 1e3:12.3f} ms', end='    ')
    print()
# (n   , m   , k   )     find_by_list         find_by_np       find_by_loop         find_by_nb    
# (5   , 5   , 5   )         0.008 ms           0.048 ms           0.021 ms           0.001 ms    
# (5   , 5   , 50  )         0.018 ms           0.031 ms           0.176 ms           0.001 ms    
# (5   , 5   , 500 )         0.132 ms           0.092 ms           1.754 ms           0.006 ms    
# (5   , 50  , 5   )         0.065 ms           0.031 ms           0.184 ms           0.001 ms    
# (5   , 50  , 50  )         0.139 ms           0.093 ms           1.756 ms           0.006 ms    
# (5   , 50  , 500 )         1.096 ms           0.684 ms          17.546 ms           0.049 ms    
# (5   , 500 , 5   )         0.658 ms           0.093 ms           1.871 ms           0.006 ms    
# (5   , 500 , 50  )         1.383 ms           0.699 ms          17.504 ms           0.051 ms    
# (5   , 500 , 500 )         9.102 ms           7.752 ms         177.754 ms           0.491 ms    
# (50  , 5   , 5   )         0.026 ms           0.061 ms           0.022 ms           0.001 ms    
# (50  , 5   , 50  )         0.054 ms           0.042 ms           0.174 ms           0.002 ms    
# (50  , 5   , 500 )         0.356 ms           0.203 ms           1.759 ms           0.006 ms    
# (50  , 50  , 5   )         0.232 ms           0.042 ms           0.185 ms           0.001 ms    
# (50  , 50  , 50  )         0.331 ms           0.205 ms           1.744 ms           0.006 ms    
# (50  , 50  , 500 )         1.332 ms           2.422 ms          17.492 ms           0.051 ms    
# (50  , 500 , 5   )         2.328 ms           0.197 ms           1.882 ms           0.006 ms    
# (50  , 500 , 50  )         3.092 ms           2.405 ms          17.618 ms           0.052 ms    
# (50  , 500 , 500 )        11.088 ms          18.989 ms         175.568 ms           0.479 ms    
# (500 , 5   , 5   )         0.205 ms           0.035 ms           0.023 ms           0.001 ms    
# (500 , 5   , 50  )         0.410 ms           0.137 ms           0.187 ms           0.001 ms    
# (500 , 5   , 500 )         2.800 ms           1.914 ms           1.894 ms           0.006 ms    
# (500 , 50  , 5   )         1.868 ms           0.138 ms           0.201 ms           0.001 ms    
# (500 , 50  , 50  )         2.154 ms           1.814 ms           1.902 ms           0.006 ms    
# (500 , 50  , 500 )         6.352 ms          16.343 ms          19.108 ms           0.050 ms    
# (500 , 500 , 5   )        19.798 ms           1.957 ms           2.020 ms           0.006 ms    
# (500 , 500 , 50  )        20.922 ms          13.571 ms          18.850 ms           0.052 ms    
# (500 , 500 , 500 )        35.947 ms         139.923 ms         189.747 ms           0.481 ms
```

Showing that Numba provides the fastest (and most memory efficient) solution, while its non-JIT accelerated version provides the slowest. The NumPy-based one and the `list`-based one come out somewhere in between, with varying speed. But for larger inputs, the `list` based one should be faster on average because it provides better short-circuiting.

Answer (score 0):

Not the most elegant solution, but it works:

Setting up (in the future, show the code to generate your example, it'll make it faster to answer):

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([['a', 'b'], ['b', 'c'], ['c', 'c'], ['c', 'b']])
b = np.array([['b', 'c'], ['a', 'b'], ['c', 'c'], ['a', 'b'], ['c', 'c']])
desired_output = [1, 0, 2, 0, 2]
```

Using the [numpy.where](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) function (as in this related question: [Is there a NumPy function to return the first index of something in an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432112/is-there-a-numpy-function-to-return-the-first-index-of-something-in-an-array))

We use `np.where` per item in each row, multiply the boolean results, and use list comprehension to pass row by row:

```
output = [np.where((x[0]==a[:,0]) * (x[1]==a[:,1]))[0][0] for x in b]
```

It gives back your desired result.

Answer (score 0):

An interesting way to do things, perhaps?

```
a.append(None)
aa = np.array(a)[:-1]                # Note 1

b.append(None)
bb = np.array(b)[:-1]

ind_arr = bb[:, None] == aa          # Note 2
np.nonzero(ind_arr)[1]
```

**Note 1**: The first step is more like an overhead to get an `object` type 1-D array. Otherwise, `numpy` forces a 2-D `str` type array, which is unhelpful for this application. Read more about it in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51879900/12983399). It also states a few alternatives.

**Note 2**: This creates a 2-D boolean mask with each element of `aa` compared with each element of `bb` for *equality*, like so: `ind_arr[i, j] = (bb[i] == aa[j])`.
The next line uses this mask and extracts the `True` values along *axis 1* (where the comparison had evaluated to `True`). This is because `aa` values in the comparison mask are along axis 1.
[Another discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21226896/12983399) to understand this better.

If you're looking for speed though, for *lists*, norok2's answer is quite a lot faster. This perhaps, can have innovative applications. Cheers!