# Vectorisation - applying the function to each element of the matrix

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, array-broadcasting

I have two arrays and the function

```
nparr1 = np.array([1,2])
nparr2 = np.array([[0.4, 0.8, 1.2, 1.6, 2]])

def fun(a,b):
    return a + b
```

I would like my output to be matrix

```
result = [
    [fun(1,0.4), fun(1,0.8), fun(1,1.2), fun(1,1.6), fun(1,2)],
    [fun(2,0.4), fun(2,0.8), fun(2,1.2), fun(2,1.6), fun(2,2)]
]
```

I figured out that running

```
np.array(np.meshgrid(nparr1, nparr2)).T
```

results in intermediate step of building this matrix

```
intermidiate_matrix = [[[1.  0.4]
  [1.  0.8]
  [1.  1.2]
  [1.  1.6]
  [1.  2. ]]

 [[2.  0.4]
  [2.  0.8]
  [2.  1.2]
  [2.  1.6]
  [2.  2. ]]]
```

It looks like a step in the right direction. But I am not sure how to proceed from here. Summation in the `fun` is arbitrary and used only as an example. The key things is that function takes two params and reduces it to single value. I was looking into `np.vectorize` but didn't have much sucess.

Comment: Do you want [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32742943/1740577)?

Comment: Consider using broadcast simply: `nparr1[:, None] + nparr2`

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is a common operation in numpy and it makes sense to make use of [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html). This is a central concept in numpy and I really recommend reading that page in the documentation and learning in detail how that works if you plan to use numpy.

Comment: I will have a read. Cheers.